# Unable to assign String from variable as sheet name

Tags: string, vba, excel

Basically, I'm trying to create a new sheet in my current workbook that has the same name as the file I select.

```
Sub ImportReport()
    '(clickable button)

    'prompt to select file, get file name (of Report)
    Dim reportFullName As String
    reportFullName = PromptGetReportFullName()

    Dim reportName As String
    'Grabs the excel file name from the full directory path
    reportName = Mid(reportFullName, InStrRev(reportFullName, "\") + 1, InStrRev(reportFullName, ".") - (InStrRev(reportFullName, "\") + 1))

    'add Sheet after last Sheet with report name
    Call AddReportSheet(reportName)

End Sub

Private Function PromptGetReportFullName() As String

    Dim startingFileDirectory As String
    startingFileDirectory = Range("A6").Text
    ChDrive FileDirectory

    PromptGetReportFullName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Report File")

End Function

Private Sub AddReportSheet(sheetName As String)
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).name = sheetName
    End With
End Sub
```

The weird part is calling `MsgBox(reportName)` in `Sub ImportReport()` works fine and gives me the file name I want, but assigning the sheet name to `reportName` in `Private Sub AddReportSheet()` fails to create a new sheet named with the `reportName` string.

If I replace `reportName` in `AddReportSheet()` with a random string like "test", the program succeeds in creating a new sheet named "test".

I'm guessing that reportName is just not stored as a string? Although I'm not sure why that would be, and I have no clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your file name contains characters that are illegal in sheet names, or maybe it is too long?  Excel has the following restrictions:

- no use of ":\/?*[]"
- not longer than 32 characters

Comment: Yup! That was exactly it! The name was too long. Thanks so much. In retrospect, that was one of the possible problems listed right on the error message. I just glossed over it.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `sheetName` as variable name in your Sub `AddReportSheet`, but you are trying to use `reportName` instead of `sheetName`. Since `reportName` variable is empty in your Sub `AddReportSheet`, it is not working. So change your variable name like this:

```
Private Sub AddReportSheet(sheetName As String)
    With ActiveWorkbook
        'REPLACED reportName WITH sheetName
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).name = sheetName
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You're right, that was a really dumb mistake. It came after trying numerous ways to do the same thing. Still, using `sheetName` doesn't work, although I don't understand why not :(

Comment: Hmm... Does `sheetName` carrying desired value in `AddReportSheet` Sub? Try to debug and see.

Comment: `MsgBox (sheetName)` in `AddReportSheet` gives me the string I want

Comment: Now that is weird. Write a simple `Sub` to add sheet with hard-coded sheetName and see if that's working or no.

Comment: ie `With ActiveWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).name = "test"`

Comment: I've tested your code and it works perfectly fine. Try it in new WorkBook. Chances are something is corrupted in your current WB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134089/discussion-between-manishchristian-and-g-t).